# Running Bindservice after the activity is destroyed

Tags: android, binding, android-service, android-music-player

I'm kinda creating a music player with binder type service.I know if I use binder I should use stopSelf in activity but is there any way that I can run the service on activity destroy.I have a seekbar in my activity.if I use startService in OnDestroy I'm getting error in service.

MainActivity

```
private ServiceConnection music=new ServiceConnection(){

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName p1, IBinder p2)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        MusicBinder binder=(MusicBinder)p2;
        registerReceiver(broadcastReciever, new IntentFilter(MusicService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
        musicSrv = binder.getService();
        musicSrv.setList(songList);
        musicBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName p1)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        if (mBroadCastIsRegistered)
        {
            try
            {
                unregisterReceiver(broadcastReciever);
                mBroadCastIsRegistered = false;}
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getClass().getName() + "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        musicBound = false;
    }
};
```

Manifest

```
<service
  android:name=".Musicservice"/>
```

I'm starting the service with thread.

Comment: "I'm kinda creating" -- could you clarify that? Are  you or aren't you creating a music player? Or are you just adapting some open source bits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can startService then bindService from activity. That way when activity can unbind when it's done but music service will keep playing until stop self is called. So use both mechanisms are required to stop.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. Why would you start the service from OnDestroy?

Comment: I want to run the service even after the activity is destroyed but I heard that if I use binder type service.the service will be destroyed as soon as the activities used the service is destroyed.

Comment: Yea try the suggestion above and service will keep running when activity is destroyed.

Comment: Which one ur method or karoly method.if it is ur method, can you please explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know Servive belongs **to the thread, where it has been created **.

So if you would like to keep the service running, after the Activity closed, you have to start it from a different place. I would recommend an Application subclass OR you can do it from an Activity with: new Thread(){...startServiceHere...}.start();

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
public void run(){
getApplicationContext().bindService(
    new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAndroidUpnpServiceImpl.class),
    serviceConnection,
    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE
);}
};
t.start();
```

//service code copied from @Samuh

Comment: Thanks karoly. Im gonna try this.

Comment: Tried your codes but I if I swipe away my app from recent tasks.I got illegal argument exception with service not registered msg.

Comment: can you add some code from manifest and the error message please ? How's the service code looks like? What methods, have your overriden ?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Service creates only in UI thread.It does not make sense to put startService  inside a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

as @bhiku mentioned, you can start you service, then bind the your activity to your running service using serviceConnection callbacks.

```
  // so start your service
  val audioPlayerServiceIntent = Intent(this, AudioPlayerService::class.java)
  Util.startForegroundService(this, audioPlayerServiceIntent)
        

  val serviceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, binder: IBinder?) {
       if (binder is AudioPlayerService.PlayerBinder) {
            playerView.player = binder.getExoPlayerInstance()
       }
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(p0: ComponentName?) {

    }
  }
  // then bind your activity to the running service
  bindService(Intent(this, AudioPlayerService::class.java), serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```